# Images not uploading to db in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, mono

I want to edit the image by using put method but when I give the path it shows 'filename' undefined .Image updating but i when skip to edit image then it shows me filename undefined

```
app.put('/about_update/:id',upload.single('avatar'),(req,res,next)=>{
console.log(res.file);
aboutus.findById(req.params.id,(err,data2)=>{   
    if(err){
       return res.send(err.message, '404 error from server');

        }
    data2.personName = req.body.personName;
    data2.designation = req.body.designation;
    data2.content = req.body.content;
    data2.avatar = req.file.filename;
    data2.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            res.send(err.message, 'err from server');
        }else{
            res.json({message:'updated successfully'});
        }       
    })

})
```

})

error:

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
    at aboutus.findById (/var/www/html/gis-react-version/api/server.js:147:33)
    at /var/www/html/gis-react-version/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4451:16
    at process.nextTick (/var/www/html/gis-react-version/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2476:28)

Comment: What is the error here?

Comment: Can u paste the complete error ?

Comment: yes i pasted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (req.file) {
       data.personName = req.body.personName;
       data.designation = req.body.designation;
       data.content = req.body.content;
       data.avatar = req.file.filename;
    }else{
       data.personName = req.body.personName;
       data.designation = req.body.designation;
       data.content = req.body.content;
   }
aboutus.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
            $set: {data}
   }).then(() => {
        res.json({message:'updated successfully'});
     }, (err) => {
         res.json({message:'err from server'});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

body-parser  handles JSON and urlencoded form submissions, not multipart (which would be the case if you're uploading images).
Thus it is showing this issue.
In order to use that ,you can simply use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) package.

Comment: actually I got the data from db but I want to change image also that meant be new image uploaded to db just replace 

when i upload only image then it didn't get any error but when i skip image to upload then it is showing like above the error

Comment: have you hosted it somewhere so that I can check it?

Comment: I haven't posted I am checking in local only